# Fetching data issue using simple like query

Tags: php, mysql

[image: job_detail - table]

[image: apply - table]

and here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
 FROM job_detail, apply 
WHERE job_detail.job_id = apply.job_id 
AND apply.end_user_id =1 
AND job_detail.jobtitle =  'barber'
AND (job_detail.Zip LIKE  '%900%' 
OR job_detail.city LIKE  '%900%' 
OR job_detail.country LIKE '%900%')
```

and it return me record of id 37 ... but my fetching data must be empty

Comment: how about using inner join?

Comment: how does id 37 pass this test? `job_detail.jobtitle =  'barber'`

Comment: actually this is problem i am total confused @dstudeba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit join syntax and see what you get

```
select a.*
From job_detail j
Join apply a
    On j.job_id = a.job_id 
    AND a.end_user_id =1 
    AND j.jobtitle =  'barber'
    AND (j.Zip LIKE  '%900%' 
    OR j.city LIKE  '%900%' 
    OR j.country LIKE '%900%')
```

Comment: Its working but why not in simple query?@Drew Pierce

Comment: Cuz u weren't using explicit join and the `where` caused a db engine brain hemorrhage

Comment: I dont see what query

Comment: same query but replace a.* with * or a.*,j.* @Drew Pierce

Comment: Hold on let we load mine up

Comment: Is country null or blank for 41

Comment: country on 41 is blank

Comment: Does it allow for nulls or is country not null in schema

Comment: I need to see the full query u r running

Comment: I am getting the results i expect